# Drupal EU Cookie Compliance module conflict with theme JQuery

Tags: 7, javascript, cookies

When I first installed the module, it'd only appear in admin pages.

After some investigation, I discovered the cause was some sort of conflict with my themes jquery: jquery-1.11.2.min.js.

If I disable it, the module works. If I enable it, the module doesn't work in non-admin pages.

The error message I'm getting is

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
```

I think the module is using a older version of jquery, and that API has since been deprecated in newer version. I can't update the the modules jquery without modifying the module itself, nor can I downgrade my theme's jquery.

How do I have the module strictly use its own jquery and not use my theme's (if that's the cause of the problem)?

Comment: Please post this issue over here: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/eu_cookie_compliance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report that must be filed to the mentioned module's issue queue, not here on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti to manage multiple versions of jQuery on your site